# Why is a call to .delay necessary after alert() to not skip an effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to understand why this works the way it does.  I'm under the impression that the alert dialog blocks script execution.  Yet the script is behaving as if execution continues behind the scenes, without updating the screen.

Take this code:

```
function highlightItems(itemA, itemB, msg) {

    $(itemA).effect("highlight", {}, 800);

    window.alert(msg);

    // $(itemB).delay(1);
    $(itemB).effect("highlight", {}, 800);
}
```

When I close the alert dialog, the highlight effect for itemB is already done. (If I close the alert quickly enough I can catch the tail end of the effect.)  It's as if the effect started before I got a chance to close the alert box.

All I can think of is that whatever effect() is using to time itself is being thrown off by the call to alert().  If I un-comment the .delay, the highlight works as expected: it begins immediately after the alert box is closed.  So would that mean the .delay function "resets" the effect timer?

This isn't a major problem... I'm just trying to understand what's going on here. My usual Google skills have failed me today.

**Edit** -- jsfiddle for an example of what I mean: [jsfiddle.net/kA2uV/](http://jsfiddle.net/kA2uV/)

**Edit 2**

This apparently only affects cases where the same .effect is used twice in a row.  If a different effect is used, the problem doesn't happen: [jsfiddle.net/yXSgu/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/yXSgu/3/)

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, jQuery animations are based on the date/time, it isn't handled primarily by setTimeout or setInterval. Time keeps on going while the javascript is halted.

Edit: I see what you mean, though i still think it has to do with date/time, maybe jQuery's internal use of $.now() in this case IS being thrown off by the alert coupled with the .delay(1)

Comment: The animate effect IS based on a setInterval, but the calculation of the animation state is based on a timestamp that gets set at the beginning of the animation, so the animation is normally 'done' by the time the alert is closed (which takes a few seconds to click and close).

Answer (score 0):

The alert function "pauses" the state of the program, so that when it's dismissed, the program will resume. the delay should come after the alert to assure that you are not waiting longer than intended.

Answer (score 0):

That's because highlight fires, but the alert doesn't wait for it to finish before launching.
Here is a modified version that works as expected. (the highlight finishes before the alert shows)

Additonally, your example doesn't 'pause' the highlight because as another poster has said, jQuery uses time values to run animations.

http://jsfiddle.net/yXSgu/

Comment: The highlight for itemA (the first .effect) does "freeze" highlighted, which is actually what I want so it isn't a problem.  That's not the part I'm confused about.  I'm wondering why the call to .effect(itemB) isn't going through its full cycle, unless I add that .delay line.

Comment: Seems like this might be a side effect of trying to call the same effect twice, and the effect using timestamps for its' animation (see my comment on @Kevin's answer) here is a perfectly working example because it uses two separate effects: http://jsfiddle.net/yXSgu/1/

Comment: You're right, it has something to do with using the same effect. (sample updated: http://jsfiddle.net/yXSgu/3/) Apparently .effect doesn't always use a new start time if it thinks a previous instance of the same effect is still running.